# Converting Raw Jupyter Notebook to JSON list using Python

Tags: python, json, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

How can I convert a [Raw Jupyter Notebook from GitHub](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/julienr/ipynb_playground/master/misc_math/homography_2d.ipynb) ([source](https://github.com/julienr/ipynb_playground/blob/master/misc_math/homography_2d.ipynb)) into a JSON file using Python?

Comment: `Save the raw Jupyter Notebook (JSON script) into Python` why exactly is this necessary?

Comment: So that I'm able to access its contents? More explicitly - I'd like to store the contents of the `Raw` page into a JSON file that I can read using, for example, the `json` library

Comment: So you wanna save the notebook json and then run it with your own parameters?

Comment: In summary, yes ^

Comment: Then you might wanna look into to [this](https://github.com/nteract/papermill)

Comment: Thanks mate - this does seem very convenient and I'll pass it onto my professor. This is a course for students who are most likely using Jupyter Notebook for the first time so I wouldn't want to complicate things further (I know it's only an extra box and a tag, but some students might not be with the update). Thanks anyway - definitely checking it out for future projects